# Wordpress slug confusion

Tags: permalinks, slug

How can I make my page url to be like this in wordpress?

Normal link: [www.google.com/about](http://www.google.com/about)

What I want: [www.google.com/any-slug/about](http://www.google.com/any-slug/about)

How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, Tabish, welcome to WPSE. I would suggest you to [add a little bit more of context, and information](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to your question and explain what you already tried, maybe also a little bit more context on your knowledge and skill with WordPress, in order to get a faster response. In the meantime, check the official documentation on [permalinks](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/) and let us know what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress down the side you goto Settings then to permalinks.

From there you select a custom structure and can put it how ever you want.

When you are creating a page after you have added in a title you can press the edit button to change the permalink.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [Permalinks Customizer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalinks-customizer/). This can help you to edit in the page or custom post type link. You can see the new link below the title of each post, you can update it here. [See screenshot](https://ps.w.org/permalinks-customizer/assets/screenshot-3.png?rev=1910298)